# Large Chi-Square value meaning

Tags: spss, p-value, chi-squared

I'm having 2 variable which I calculate Chi-Square to 103 observations.
I have large Chi-Square value (Pearson) of 199.74 associated with Degree of Freedom DF of 25.
My question is that: Is this large value for Chi-Square normal?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It would be highly unusual if the variables were not associated in the population of interest and the data were randomly sampled from the population. If the variables were strongly associated in the population, it might not be so unusual.

Answer (score 0):

A chi-square value in itself must be compared to the **critical values** of that level of **significance** (e.g. `p=0.05`) and number of **degrees of freedom**.

For 25 df and a p-value of 0.05, that critical value is 37.652 based on this table:

> https://www.medcalc.org/manual/chi-square-table.php.

Your question could have been posed as "Is this large value for Chi-Square **statistically significant (if a significant p is defined as 0.05)**?"

Which it is because your chi-square value is higher than the critical value (for `df=25` and `p=0.05`).